# How do you add a suffix to $Body result?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to find out how to add a suffix to a field data in an email.  How would add " of 42" to the end of the field data?

```
$Body .= $reg_count ' of 42';

or

$Body .= $reg_count " of 42";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Body .= $reg_count . " of 42";
```

You didn't concatenate `$reg_count` and `" of 42"`

Answer (score 1):

you should concatnate variable and string using concatenation operatr (.)

```
$Body .= $reg_count . ' of 42';
```

Comment: @beginner what is wrong with you. i was right in my answer. using double quotes or concatenation operator is preference. and i prefer concatenation rather then using double quotes for readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $Body .= $reg_count." of 42";
  or
  $Body .= "$reg_count of 42";
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way as with every other string.

```
'foo' . 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
 $Body .= "$reg_count  of 42";
```

Answer (score 0):

$Body .= $reg_count . ' of 42';
or
$Body .= "$reg_count of 42";
Use any of these